# C# MySQL Inserting Same Data into 2 Different Tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

So I tried making a code for adding 2 same data within 2 different tables which is
"studentinfo" and "logindb"
I tried doing this

```
enter code heprivate void buttonRegisterStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String connection = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=votingdb";
        //Inserting Data
        String insertDataInfo = @"INSERT INTO studentinfo (firstname,lastname,username,password,email) values 
                                   ('"+this.textBoxFirstName.Text+"','"+this.textBoxLastName.Text+"','"+this.textBoxUsername.Text+
                                   "','"+ this.textBoxPassword.Text + "','"+ this.textBoxEmail.Text + "')";
        String insertDataLogin = @"INSERT INTO logindb (username,password) values ('"+this.textBoxUsername.Text+"','"
                                    +this.textBoxPassword.Text+"')";
        //Connection
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        MySqlCommand datainfo = new MySqlCommand(insertDataInfo,con);
        MySqlCommand datalogin = new MySqlCommand(insertDataLogin, con);
        MySqlDataReader datareaderinfo;
        MySqlDataReader datareaderlogin;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            datareaderinfo = datainfo.ExecuteReader();
            datareaderlogin = datalogin.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Student Register Successfully!");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to Register" + ex);
        }

    }
```

Resulting to Error which says there may only one mysqldatareader in the code. How can I add the same data to the different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a datareader if you don't want to read data. Simple use the [ExecuteNonQuery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm) on your command:

```
datainfo.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And don't forget to open en close your connection!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a data reader for insert statements, you should simply use `ExecuteNonQuery`.
Please note that your current queries are a security hazard as they are vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. 
Instead of concatenating user inputs as strings to create your SQL statements, use parameterized queries.
For more information, read [How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks)

An improved version of the main parts in your code is this:

```
var insertDataInfo = @"INSERT INTO studentinfo (firstname,lastname,username,password,email) values 
                            (@firstName, @lastName, @userName, @passwordHash, @email)";                 

var insertDataLogin = @"INSERT INTO logindb (username,password) values (@userName, @passwordHash)";

var datainfo = new MySqlCommand(insertDataInfo,con);
datainfo.Parameters.Add("@firstName", DbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBoxFirstName.Text;
datainfo.Parameters.Add("@lastName", DbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBoxLastName.Text;
datainfo.Parameters.Add("@userName", DbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBoxUsername.Text;
datainfo.Parameters.Add("@passwordHash", DbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBoxPassword.Text;
datainfo.Parameters.Add("@email", DbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBoxEmail.Text;

var datalogin = new MySqlCommand(insertDataLogin, con);
datalogin.Parameters.Add("@userName", DbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBoxUsername.Text;
datalogin.Parameters.Add("@passwordHash", DbType.VarChar).Value = this.textBoxPassword.Text;

datainfo.ExecuteNonQuery();
datalogin.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, you are storing passwords as plain text in your database.
That's a really big security hole. [You should be storing salted hash values of your passwords instead](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) - but that's getting a little too broad for this answer so I'll leave that part up for you to read and apply.